# What is wrong with pattern matching of existential types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, existential-type

Why it is not possible to pattern match existential types in `let`/`where`, while it is doable in all other places?

**TL;DR** I have a funny error during `let` pattern matching of existential types:

```
error:
• My brain just exploded
  I can't handle pattern bindings for existential or GADT data constructors.
  Instead, use a case-expression, or do-notation, to unpack the constructor.
• In the pattern: MC q
  In a pattern binding: MC q = x
  In the expression: let MC q = x in bar q
```

**Details:** let us start with some simple code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class MyClass a where
  foo :: a -> Int

instance MyClass Int where
  foo = id

instance MyClass Char where
  foo = const 4

data MC = forall a. MyClass a => MC a

bar :: MyClass a => a -> Int
bar = (+1) . foo
```

This function runs great:

```
baz :: MC -> Int
baz (MC q) = bar q
```

and this:

```
qux :: MC -> Int
qux x = case x of
          MC q -> bar q
```

even this:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity

osе :: MC -> Int
ose x = runIdentity $ do MC q <- pure x
                         pure $ bar q
```

**but** these two fail:

```
rol :: MC -> Int
rol x = let MC q = x
        in bar q

zed :: MC -> Int
zed x = bar q
  where MC q = x
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question was well posed, but make sure you search for existing questions before posting a new one.

Comment: `let` and `where` involve lazy (AKA irrefutable) patterns, which do not force the argument (`x`, above). It would be very weird if laziness was lost only because there's a typeclass dictionary to unpack, especially because said dictionary does not explicitly occur in the code.